Slurm Job Array and quotas
I'm using hydra to launch parallel jobs on a slurm cluster. I can set the maximum number or running jobs using the keyword:
array_parallelism = 3. Supposing I want to submit 20 jobs, hydra will create a .sh file with the option --array=0-19%3 as mentioned in the slurm repository (https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html).
The policy of our cluster is that a user can not have more than 10 jobs counting both the running and pending jobs. Using squeue I see that this command spawns 20 jobs but only 3 (at maximum) are effectively running. This is correct in the sense that I can control the number of running jobs but not the number of queued jobs.
I would like to know if there is a combination of slurm arguments for having at maximum 10 jobs (pending or running) avoiding to break the rules but still use the power of the job array.

I am pretty sure there isn't. If slurm knows about it it counts toward the MaxSubmitJobs count. The only possibility I see is to handle it inside the scripts somehow, e.g. have a justom launcher that schedules further jobs (needs to stay alive), run some steps sequentially in one job or schedule other jobs at the end of your script.

Thank you @Daraan. As soon as you need to search inside a grid of parameters, the number of combinations grows very fast and it results very convenient to let hydra manage all the combinations. But as you mentioned I need to create a custom launcher
